# http requests returning to the wrong thread in golang

Tags: http, go, thread-safety

I'm having a real head scratcher of a problem. I'm syncing data for clients from an external api. Currently it's structured like this

```golang
func SyncInitHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    accounts := data.GetAccounts()

    done := make(chan error)
    var numRequests int

    for _, account := range accounts {
        numRequests++
        go func(a models.Account) {
            subTaskURL := fmt.Sprintf("http://localhost:8080/sync/account/%v", a.Id)
            _, err := http.Get(subTaskURL)
            done <- err
        }(account)
    }

    for i := 0; i < numRequests; i++ {
        <-done
    }
}

func SyncAccountHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    accountId, _ := strconv.ParseInt(vars["account-id"], 10, 64)
    account, _ := data.GetAccount(accountId)

    externalAPIURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://www.example.com/account/%v", account.ApiToken)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", apiUrl, nil)
    client := http.Client{} // urlfetch.Client(c)
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    apiResp := models.ApiRespModel{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &apiResp)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("An Error Occurred Parsing JSON: %v", err)
        return
    }

    log.Printf("Account API Token: %v, Response API Token: %v", account.ApiToken, apiResp.Token)
}
```

What should happen is that the Account API Token printed and the response Api Token should be the same (i.e. the returned data is for the same account that requested it). What is happening is that the tokens don't match, and the wrong data is being returned to the wrong account.

How is this even possible? As you can see, the external API requests are being spawned in separate requests on the local server. Go http requests are supposed to be thread safe aren't they?

Comment: The `subTaskURL := fmt.Sprintf("/sync/account/%v", a.Id); _, err := http.Get(subTaskURL)` doesn't seem right. I don't think it does what you expect it to, and even if it did I don't think that's a sound design. I mean is your init handler invoking the other handler using http? That would make sense only if the handlers belong to separate services. And passing a relative path to `http.Get`, that can't actually work? Or does it?

Comment: You're right, I'll edit that in the question we're not actually making a request to a relative path. It's just a path on localhost

Comment: "Go http requests are supposed to be thread safe aren't they?" isn't relevant - you're not sharing any `http.Request` values between goroutines here. But to the root issue, "the Account API Token printed and the response Api Token should be the same" isn't demonstrated here, as your final `log.Printf` doesn't pass any values in for the placeholders, so there's no way to be certain where the issue is.

Comment: @Adrian, oops forgot to put those values in. Sorry about that. I've updated the question

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the API you're calling is returning the correct account for the ID it receives as parameter?

Comment: @Adrian, as far as I can tell yes. If I try the requests individually they always return the right data. It's only calling them like this that wires get crossed

Comment: @hobberwickey What does `SyncInitHandler` have to do with the issue? Does `SyncAccountHandler` work when you hit `http://localhost:8080/sync/account/<id>` manually with a browser, or curl? Is it failing only when the requests are issued by `SyncInitHandler`?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, if I call the `SyncAccountHandler` directly, it's only sending out requests for one account so there are no wires to cross. It's only when there are multiple instances of `SyncAccountHandler` running concurrently (which is what `SyncInitHandler` does), that the issue shows up

Comment: @hobberwickey and have you tried hitting the external service manually? Do you get the correct api token if you do `curl -X POST https://www.example.com/account/<api-token>`?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, I've tried the requests with Postman

Comment: @hobberwickey the code that you've shared looks *like* it should be able to handle concurrent traffic, so it's the code that you haven't shared that's most likely the culprit. For example is the code in the question exactly the same (apart from the example service url) as the one you're executing? Is `data.GetAccount` safe for concurrency? Are you using `http.Client{}` or `urlfetch.Client(c)`? If `urlfetch.Client(c)` is that safe for concurrency? Did you omit anything from the handler's code that is potentially unsafe for concurrent use?